# P2Pool Node Latency

Tags: p2pool, latency

Just wondering what I can do to reduce the latency of my node. I have periods of .4s latency and it slowly drifts upwards. This seems to be a trend as the latency has been rising steadily. It doesn't seem to be related to network traffic. I was just wondering if this is just systemic of p2pool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latency measured is the time it takes for your bitcoind to respond to getblocktemplate requests. It shouldn't matter too much, and the rising time is simply your node learning about more and more transactions and making bigger templates for P2Pool to work on. There's some command line options for bticoind which let you fine tune minimum fees and the like for accepting unconfirmed transactions which may have an effect on the speed of return.

Comment: Overall I have seen it growing and was fearful that my link to the p2p network would delay my shares and cause orphans. Although I haven't seen many incidents of that. Thanks for clearing my FUD.  
Is bitcoind much leaner or faster than using the core? I am trying to speed my node up as best as possible.

Comment: The GUI and non GUI versions are essentially equivalent in terms of RPC speed. Main thing to be sure of is that if you are using an AntMiner device the "submit stale shares" option must be on or else you are throwing away income for the pool. You can use the [High Speed Relay Network](http://bitcoinrelaynetwork.org/) to speed up your discovery of new blocks on the Bitcoin network.

Comment: I do have an Ant device and was not aware of the 'submit stale shares' option. It appears to be a command line flag, not part an option in the GUI. The high speed relay network sounds interesting. Reading about it now.